# Как правильно посчитать контрольную сумму tcp пакета?

Tags: алгоритм, golang, сеть, tcp-ip

Пытаюсь реализовать алгоритм подсчета контрольной суммы при помощи данной [ссылки](https://gist.github.com/david-hoze/0c7021434796997a4ca42d7731a7073a) 
Вот пример слайса байтов и контрольные суммы для него.

```
[69 0 0 60 179 32 64 0 64 6 108 0 192 168 77 61 192 168 77 13 203 50 0 22 69 21 146 157 0 0 
0 0 160 194 250 240 65 21 0 0 2 4 5 180 4 2 8 10 38 105 38 58 0 0 0 0 1 3 3 7]
src chkSumOriginaltcp = 0x4115 calc chkSumFaketcp = 0x72e8
[69 0 0 60 0 0 64 0 64 6 31 33 192 168 77 13 192 168 77 61 0 22 203 50 88 167 128 107 69 21 
146 158 160 82 113 32 198 58 0 0 2 4 5 180 4 2 8 10 246 88 53 174 38 105 38 58 1 3 3 7]
src chkSumOriginaltcp = 0xc63a calc chkSumFaketcp = 0xa550
```

А также мой код для реализации, подскажите что я делаю не так.

```
func main(){
        var buff = make([]byte,len(payload))
        copy(buff,payload)
        ip, _ := ipv4.ParseHeader(buff)
        checkSum := chksum(ip,buff[ip.Len:])
        tcp := payload[ip.Len:]
        checkSumTcp := binary.BigEndian.Uint16(tcp[16:])
        fmt.Printf("src chkSumOriginaltcp = %#x calc chkSumFaketcp = %#x\n",checkSumTcp,checkSum)
}

    //https://gist.github.com/david-hoze/0c7021434796997a4ca42d7731a7073a
  func chksum(iph *ipv4.Header,payload []byte)uint16{

                // https://github.com/mikioh/-stdyng/blob/master/afpacket.go
                var htons = func(i uint16) uint16 {return (i<<8)&0xff00 | i>>8}

                tcpLen := iph.TotalLen - iph.Len
                src := iph.Src
                dst := iph.Dst
                var csum uint32

                for i := 0; i < 16; i += 2 {
                    csum += uint32(src[i]) << 8
                    csum += uint32(src[i+1])
                    csum += uint32(dst[i]) << 8
                    csum += uint32(dst[i+1])
                }

                csum += uint32(htons(6)) // TCP PROTO
                csum += uint32(htons(uint16(tcpLen)))

                // old chksum
                payload[16] = 0
                payload[17] = 0

                var i int
                for tcpLen > 1 {
                    csum += uint32(payload[i]) << 8
                    csum += uint32(payload[i+1])
                    tcpLen -= 2
                    i++
                }

                if tcpLen % 2 == 1 {
                    csum += uint32(payload[tcpLen - 1]) << 8
                }

                for csum > 0xffff{
                    csum = (csum >> 16) + (csum & 0xffff)
                }
                return ^uint16(csum)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func chksum(data []byte, srcip, dstip []byte) uint16 {
     data[16],data[17] = 0,0 //zero on original check sum
   psheader := []byte{
     srcip[0], srcip[1], srcip[2], srcip[3],
     dstip[0], dstip[1], dstip[2], dstip[3],
     0,
     6,                  //  TCP
     0, byte(len(data)), //  length (16 bits)
   }

   csum := make([]byte, 0, len(psheader)+len(data))
   csum = append(csum, psheader...)
   csum = append(csum, data...)


   lenSumThis := len(csum)
   var word uint16
   var sum uint32
   for i := 0; i+1 < lenSumThis; i += 2 {
     word = uint16(csum[i])<<8 | uint16(csum[i+1])
     sum += uint32(word)
   }
   if lenSumThis%2 != 0 {
           sum += uint32(csum[len(csum)-1])
   }

   sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff)
   sum = sum + (sum >> 16)

   return uint16(^sum)
 }
```